# Use decorator to change argument of a decorated function

Tags: python, decorator

## Background

I want to perform different methods to the same data. Different methods are variants of an original method, only with different arguments for `param:p3`.

```
# This is original method
def method(p1,p2,p3,data):
    return data + p1 + p2 + p3
method(p1=1, p2=2, p3=3, data=10)
```

> 16

```
# By changing param:p3, I can define 3 methods based on original method.
# but it seems stupid and very unclear...
def method1(*args, **kw):
    return method(*args, **kw, p3 = 1)
def method2(*args, **kw):
    return method(*args, **kw, p3 = 2)
def method3(*args, **kw):
    return method(*args, **kw, p3 = 3)
method1(p1=1,p2=2,data =10),\
method2(p1=1,p2=3, data =100)
```

> (14,106)

## Question

Is there any decorator to revise my original `method` to any variant, like `method1`?

```
# After decorated, method equals to method1
@decorator(p3 = 1)
def method(p1,p2,p3,data):
    return data + p1 + p2 + p3

# After decorated, method equals to method2
@decorator(p3 = 2)
def method(p1,p2,p3,data):
    return data + p1 + p2 + p3
```

Or, Shouldn't I use a decorator to satisfy my demand, maybe a class instead?

Comment: Have you looked into `functools.partial`?

Comment: @rchome Thank you! I will check `partial`, It seems can satisfy my need

Answer (score 4):

To flesh out rchome's comment, you can use functools.partial as follows:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def method(p1,p2,p3,data):
...     return data + p1 + p2 + p3
>>> method1 = partial(method, p3=1)
>>> method2 = partial(method, p3=2)
>>> method3 = partial(method, p3=3)
>>> method1(p1=1,p2=2,data=10)
14
>>> method2(p1=1,p2=2,data=10)
15
>>> method3(p1=1,p2=2,data=10)
16
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use decorator to do the same thing as follows:

```
# this is a decorator factory
def de_fac(**out_kw):
    def my_decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print('inside function arguments:',{*args})
            print('inside function keywords:',{**kw})
            print("outside decorator factory\'s arguments:", {**out_kw})
            # override {**kw} with {**out_kw}
            return f(*args, **{**kw, **out_kw})
        return wrapper
    return my_decorator


@de_fac(p3=1)
def method_to_be_dec(p1,p2,p3,data):
    return data + p1 + p2 + p3

# it's same
method_to_be_dec(p1=1, p2=2, data=10), method1(p1=1, p2=2, data=10)
```

> inside function arguments: set()
> inside function keywords: {'p1': 1, 'p2': 2, 'data': 10}
> outside decorator factory's arguments: {'p3': 1}
> (14, 14)

Comment: In the code above, we use decorator to override function parameters. I have one question further: can we use decorator to override function body?

Comment: What’s the point of using a decorator in this way? You could’ve just put p3=1 inside the function body. And if you want to override the function body, just write a different body rather than adding a decorator.

Comment: I agree that `functools.partial` is prefered in this post. I have just learned something about decorator, and I want to try anything with decorator to figure out in what situation we actually need a decorator.